# Is app store product id a sensitive data?

Tags: security, app-store

Developing the store of my app I'm wandering if the product ids of the in app purchase is a sensitive data. My goal is to store them on the server to be able to upload them on the fly when there is a special offers for example so if this is sensitive data that can be used to trick the shop or anything else should it be protected or it doesn't matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Product IDs of inApp purchase in not a sensitive data. There is no harm keeping It stored into server side.

But whenever you Add new inApp purchase first you will need to send it for Apple review. Directly you can't make it usable.

So for approval of inApp purchase you will must have to submit new version of the application with that inApp purchase will be sent for approval.

So eventually there is no meaning for keeping it on server.

Hope it helps to everyone.

Comment: I have seen an old post saying that in app purchases can be reviewed separately from the app. http://gamesfromwithin.com/in-app-purchases-part-4 did that changed recently?

Comment: After further digging it appears that in app purchase can be submitted without a new version of the app (as long as the first in app purchase ever is done with a new version of the app). https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/dev1986a0e5c